# Trouble finding average and total when getting information from a .txt file

Tags: java, average

In my object oriented programming course I have an assignment which requires me to  develop a java code that prints out payroll information for a fake company while using the information from a .txt file. I was able to get it to print out the employee names and everything but I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding how I would get the average of the salaries, I have started a method to do so and it is commented out in the code below. Any help would be appreciated.

Employee class:

```
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String rank;
    private double salary;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String rank, double salary) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }
    public void setRank(String rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

and

prog5 class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Prog5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String firstName = null;
        String lastName = null;
        String rank = null;
        double salary = 0.0;
        Scanner inFile = null;
        Employee[] arr = new Employee[99];
        int num = 0;

        try {
            inFile = new Scanner( new File ( "c:\\Users\\admin\\workspace\\Shumaker5\\src\\employees.txt"));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(" File not found");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //read file
        while(inFile.hasNext()) {
            try {
                firstName = inFile.next();
                lastName = inFile.next();
                rank = inFile.next();
                salary = inFile.nextDouble();
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.err.println("File format error");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            Employee emp = new Employee(firstName, lastName, rank, salary);
            arr[num] = emp;
            num++;

            /**
             * method to calculate average
             * @param temperatures
             * @param counter
             * @return
             */
        /** public static double average( double[] salary, int num )
            {
                double sum = 0;
                for( int t = 0; t < num; t++)
            {
                    sum += salary[t];
            }
                return (double) sum / num; 
            } */

            System.out.println(emp);
        }   
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Wayne Industries");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number of Employees:    " + num);
        System.out.println("Average Salary:   ");
        System.out.println("Annual Total:    ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%-15s %-15s %-6s %-8s \n", "Last Name", "First Name", "Rank", "Salary");
        System.out.println();

        for(int x = 0; x < num; x++) {
            System.out.printf("%-15s %-15s %-6s %-8.2f\n", arr[x].getLastName(),
                    arr[x].getFirstName(), arr[x].getRank(), arr[x].getSalary());
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you  point out where you are having trouble? When you have a specific question, you should avoid just putting all your code...

Comment: I said that the problem area was commented out. its in the prog class

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to retrieve salary first as a string, then extract the double (e.g. with Double.parseDouble(salary)). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close. We just need to pass the array of employees (rather than their salaries) and calculate the average in the method. An example is provided below:

```
public static double average( Employee[] employees ){
        double sum = 0;
        for( int t = 0; t < employees.length; t++){
            sum += employee[t].getSalary();
        }
        return (double) sum / employees.length; 
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. This is my first time working with a text file so i was a little lost this helps immensley

Comment: I am still getting two errors with the updated code, in the return statement i am getting void methods cannot return a value. and on the public static double line its saying illegal modifier for the variable average; only final is permitted

Comment: You may be pasting the method into wrong place. Can you please make sure the method is not being pasted into existing method?

Comment: I moved it around to a number of different places just to be sure, but the errors stayed the same regardless of where I put them.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the Employee class.
The employee contains all info you need and you have captured everything for each individual employee.

**How to calculate the average salary?**

1. As suggested by another response, you can change the signature of your average function in a way that the array of Employee's are passed as input parameter. Then inside the commented code (for calculating the average salary), replace "salary[t]" by employee[t].getSalary().
2. The other approach is to keep track of sum of the salaries and total number of employees while you are reading the file line by line and storing their info in Employee class object. With this approach you do not need to iterate through the array one more time.

Some corner cases you may want to consider are:

- What if the file is empty? You may want to add a if condition to prevent dividing by zero?
- How do you plan to handle overflow? For example if the sum of salaries cannot be fi into an integer value? Some suggestions are:

  - using unsigned int instead of int for sum variable (or unsigned long int). this is because there is no negative salary and you can cover larger range of numbers.
  - 